# Using PySimpleGUI, how could I make it download a file with a progress bar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

I would like to know how I could make a PySimpleGUI progress bar that updates accordingly to downloading a file.

*(Since I am on macOS I'll have to change the file directory but if your on Windows or Linux at the moment, just write it in that directory format since I know macOS's directory structure.)*

I know what I could do to download the file *(use requests for JSON API's and url-lib to retrieve the file)*.

So if anyone could please help me with my making of this, thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are your specific problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example for you,

[image]

```py
import threading
from time import sleep
from random import randint
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def download_file(window):
    for count in range(0, 101, 2):     # Download file block by block
        sleep(0.1) 
        window.write_event_value('Next', count)

sg.theme("DarkBlue")

progress_bar = [
    [sg.ProgressBar(100, size=(40, 20), pad=(0, 0), key='Progress Bar'),
     sg.Text("  0%", size=(4, 1), key='Percent'),],
]

layout = [
    [sg.Button('Download')],
    [sg.pin(sg.Column(progress_bar, key='Progress', visible=False))],
]
window       = sg.Window('Title', layout, size=(600, 80), finalize=True,
    use_default_focus=False)
download     = window['Download']
progress_bar = window['Progress Bar']
percent      = window['Percent']
progress     = window['Progress']
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Download':
        count = 0
        download.update(disabled=True)
        progress_bar.update(current_count=0, max=100)
        progress.update(visible=True)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=download_file, args=(window, ), daemon=True)
        thread.start()
    elif event == 'Next':
        count = values[event]
        progress_bar.update(current_count=count)
        percent.update(value=f'{count:>3d}%')
        window.refresh()
        if count == 100:
            sleep(1)
            download.update(disabled=False)
            progress.update(visible=False)

window.close()
```