# +50 PySimpleGUI: Progress bar that links to a downloading file (I've actually got code this time)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Linking on from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66175015/using-pysimplegui-how-could-i-make-it-download-a-file-with-a-progress-bar), I have some what some code.

*(Thanks to one of the people who responded, @Jason Yang)*

I have edited their code to this:

```py
import threading
from time import sleep
from random import randint
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import urllib.request
from clint.textui import progress
import requests

url = "http://mirrors.evowise.com/linuxmint/debian/lmde-4-cinnamon-64bit.iso"
path = '/Users/me/test.iso'

def download_file(window):
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        with open(path, 'wb') as f:
            total_length = int(r.headers.get('content-length'))
            for chunk in progress.bar(r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024), expected_size=(total_length/1024) + 1): 
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)
                    f.flush()

        window.write_event_value('Next', count)

sg.theme("DarkBlue")

progress_bar = [
    [sg.ProgressBar(100, size=(40, 20), pad=(0, 0), key='Progress Bar'),
     sg.Text("  0%", size=(4, 1), key='Percent'),],
]

layout = [
    [sg.Button('Download')],
    [sg.pin(sg.Column(progress_bar, key='Progress', visible=False))],
]
window       = sg.Window('Title', layout, size=(520, 80), finalize=True,
    use_default_focus=False)
download     = window['Download']
progress_bar = window['Progress Bar']
percent      = window['Percent']
progressB     = window['Progress']
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Download':
        count = 0
        download.update(disabled=True)
        progress_bar.update(current_count=0, max=100)
        progressB.update(visible=True)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=download_file, args=(window, ), daemon=True)
        thread.start()
    elif event == 'Next':
        count = values[event]
        progress_bar.update(current_count=count)
        percent.update(value=f'{count:>3d}%')
        window.refresh()
        if count == 100:
            sleep(1)
            download.update(disabled=False)
            progressB.update(visible=False)

window.close()
```

So I have made the download function BUT I can't seem to find a way to get the percentage and link it up to the progress bar + the percentage text.

*(Again thanks to @Jason Yang for their original code which I edited to download the from the URL)*

Update, so far I have this code:

```py
import threading
from time import sleep
from random import randint
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import urllib.request
from clint.textui import progress
import requests

url = "http://mirrors.evowise.com/linuxmint/debian/lmde-4-cinnamon-64bit.iso"
path = '/Users/I hate this/test.iso'
percentE = None

def download_file(window):
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        with open(path, 'wb') as f:
            total_length = int(r.headers.get('content-length'))
            for chunk in progress.bar(r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024), expected_size=(total_length/1024) + 1): 
                if chunk:
                    expected_size=(total_length/1024)
                    f.write(chunk)
                    f.flush()
                    percentE = 1024*(total_length+1)/expected_size
                    print(int(percentE))

        window.write_event_value('Next', count)

sg.theme("DarkBlue")

progress_bar = [
    [sg.ProgressBar(100, size=(40, 20), pad=(0, 0), key='Progress Bar'),
     sg.Text("  0%", size=(4, 1), key='Percent'),],
]

layout = [
    [sg.Button('Download')],
    [sg.pin(sg.Column(progress_bar, key='Progress', visible=False))],
]
window       = sg.Window('Title', layout, size=(520, 80), finalize=True,
    use_default_focus=False)
download     = window['Download']
progress_bar = window['Progress Bar']
percent      = window['Percent']
progressB     = window['Progress']
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Download':
        count = 0
        download.update(disabled=True)
        progress_bar.update(current_count=0, max=100)
        progressB.update(visible=True)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=download_file, args=(window, ), daemon=True)
        thread.start()
    elif event == 'Next':
        count = values[event]
        progress_bar.update(current_count=count)
        percent.update(value=f'{count:>3d}%')
        window.refresh()
        if count == 100:
            sleep(1)
            download.update(disabled=False)
            progressB.update(visible=False)

window.close()
```

But it doesn't seem to print a percent. And @Jason Yang, there is no `i` so please edit that comment

Comment: put this statement in your for loop `window.write_event_value('Next', count)` where `count` is the percent of downloaded chucks and you need to calculate it.

Comment: How would I calculate it though? I don't see anything I could calculate with it.

Comment: How about `int(1024*(i+1)/expected_size)` ?

Comment: Wait how did you work that out?

Comment: Oh and by the way there is no `i` in the code

Comment: Oh... I think you may know what I mean the `i ` in a for loop. you can get it by python keyword `enumerate`. Enumerate is a built-in function of Python. besides that, you should check the condition about `if count == 100:` if it will exactly happen.

Comment: Ok well I am confused, I think I should just give up on this.

Comment: I know what `for i in list: print(i)` does and what `for i in list` does :)

Comment: Enumerate returns 2 items instead of 1 like in plain for-loop.  `for item in my_list`.   To add a count of the items, then use:  `for i, item in enumerate(my_list)`.

Answer (score 0):

Example for you ...

```
import threading
from time import sleep
from random import randint
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import urllib.request
import requests

path = 'd:/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar'
percentE = None

def download_file(window):

    url = "https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.141/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar"
    with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
        chunk_size = 64*1024
        total_length = int(r.headers.get('content-length'))
        total = total_length//chunk_size if total_length % chunk_size == 0 else total_length//chunk_size + 1
        with open(path, 'wb') as f:
            for i, chunk in enumerate(r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size)):
                f.write(chunk)
                percentE = int((i+1)/total*100)
                window.write_event_value('Next', percentE)

sg.theme("DarkBlue")

progress_bar = [
    [sg.ProgressBar(100, size=(40, 20), pad=(0, 0), key='Progress Bar'),
     sg.Text("  0%", size=(4, 1), key='Percent'),],
]

layout = [
    [sg.Button('Download')],
    [sg.pin(sg.Column(progress_bar, key='Progress', visible=False))],
]
window       = sg.Window('Title', layout, size=(520, 80), finalize=True,
    use_default_focus=False)
download     = window['Download']
progress_bar = window['Progress Bar']
percent      = window['Percent']
progressB     = window['Progress']
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Download':
        count = 0
        download.update(disabled=True)
        progress_bar.update(current_count=0, max=100)
        progressB.update(visible=True)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=download_file, args=(window, ), daemon=True)
        thread.start()
    elif event == 'Next':
        count = values[event]
        progress_bar.update(current_count=count)
        percent.update(value=f'{count:>3d}%')
        window.refresh()
        if count == 100:
            sleep(1)
            download.update(disabled=False)
            progressB.update(visible=False)

window.close()
```